# I python notebook is very slow when I run it on my laptop

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I python notebook is very slow and not working properly. For example consider the below example code.

code:

```
%matplotlib inline 

from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from pattern import web

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_past_and_future_population'
website_html = requests.get(url).text
print website_html
```

This code should get all the html code from the respective web page. Some times I am able to execute the code. Some times I am not. Please help me out with this issue

Comment: Does it run fast when you run that code outside ipython?

Comment: The example code is fetching a webpage, so it might be slow or fail because your internet connection is slow, rather than because IPython is slow. Also, instead of getting the webpage over and over, why not download it to a file, and then use that file?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. My internet connection speed is 4 mbps, this is more than enafe for running small applications. The problem was with Ipython installation. I re-installed it and now it is working fine.